# How to initialize Vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I initialize an vector using this code below there was an error.

```
vector<int> e;

for(int i=0;i<10;i+)
{
e[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: [`e.push_back(some_data);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) - there is nothing in the `vector` yet, so you can't try to access it with `[]`.

Comment: `vector<int> e(10, 0);` - initialize vector with 10 elements all with value 0.

Answer (score 2):

As BoBTFish already said you can't access elements of a vector with [] since nothing is in the vector. You have several options on how to do this.

a. use push_back instead of "=" this will look like

```
vector<int> e;
for (i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
  e.push_back(0);
```

b. initialize and empty vector like this

```
vector<int> e(10);
for (i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
  e[i] = 0;
```

c. Initialize a vector of size 10 filled with 0s like this

```
vector<int> e(10,0);
```

Comment: what does the push_back do?

Comment: It basically adds an element to the end of your vector. It increases the size of vector by one and assigns your given value to that newly created last element.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to write

```
std::vector<int> e( 10 );
```

if you want that each element was equal to zero.

Otherwise you can write

```
std::vector<int> e( 10, value );
```

If you have a vector of type `std::vector<T>` then declaration

```
std::vector<T> v( n );
```

is equivalent to

```
std::vector<T> v( n, T() );
```